# Difference between Debugger.Launch and Debugger.Break

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, system.diagnostics

What's the difference between

```
Debugger.Launch();
Debugger.Break();
```

?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Reading the documentation, it sounds like `Launch` does nothing if the debugger is attached - it doesn't actually *break* (although I haven't verified this).

`Break` *asks* to launch the debugger (if not attached), and *does* do the break.

In reality, it is unlikely you'd have more than one `Launch` point... if that.

Answer (score 21):

Launch will start a debugger when one is available.  But is just ignored if there is none available.  Break will crash the program if no debugger is available.

Comment: Especially the hint to the crash is helpful. I just found out that my release-version application crashed because of a forgotten debug.break. I thought the calls would only be executed in the debug version...I was wrong...

Answer (score 11):

More subtle differences:

1. If a debugger is already attached, Debugger.Launch is a [nop](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nop#Noun); whereas
   `Debugger.Break` will always break
   into the debugger.
2. Launching a
   debugger does not actually break
   into the debugger. For example, in
   Visual Studio, `Debugger.Launch` will attach a
   debugger to the running process, but
   then you still need to do a Debug |
   Break in Visual Studio to actually break under
   the debugger.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure if anyone actually tried what's the difference or if it's different between .NET Framework and .NET 5 but this is the behavior when I test it:

[image: result when running the example]

After clicking OK VS will break on `Debugger.Launch()` (despite other answerers saying it will not):

[image]

However the debugger will *not* break on `Debugger.Launch()` if it is already attached.

If I pack my project as a dotnet Tool everything is the same except it doesn't know where to break:

[image]

**TL;DR:** In .NET 5:

With debugger attached:

- `.Launch()` will do nothing
- `.Break()` will break

Without debugger attached:

- `.Launch()` will ask to attach a debugger and if you do, it will break at `.Launch()`
- `.Break()` will do nothing (no exceptions)

---

Example.csproj:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

Program.cs:

```cs
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

Console.WriteLine("Before break");

Debugger.Break();

Console.WriteLine("After break");

Console.WriteLine("Before Launch");

Debugger.Launch();

Console.WriteLine("After Launch");
```

Comment: I verified the same "without debugger attached" behaviour with .NET Framework.