# How to debug a RTD Server C# Implementation

Tags: c#, excel, com, rtd

I'm trying do learn how to implement a RTD Server for Excel.

I found this project https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5343545/Create-Csharp-DCOM-Simple-Server-to-Use-Excel-RTD that I could build and use it in the excel with success.

But to understand the code I need to debug the code setting some breakpoints and inpecting line by line and the variables.

How can I debug a COM RTD Server C# implementation in Visual Studio ?

Comment: Just start or attach to the process where code runs, put a breakpoint in a line of your code and it should work. Another solution is to put a `Debugger.Launch();` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debugger.launch) code somewhere and just-in-time debugging will ask you how you want to debug. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3759308/difference-between-debugger-launch-and-debugger-break

Comment: thanks @SimonMourier. using attach to the process works. Would you like to post an asnwer ? I will check it as asnwered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just start or [attach to the process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/attach-to-running-processes-with-the-visual-studio-debugger#BKMK_Attach_to_a_running_process) where code runs, put a breakpoint in a line of your code and it should work.

Another solution is to put a [Debugger.Launch()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debugger.launch) statement somewhere in your code and [just-in-time debugging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debug-using-the-just-in-time-debugger) will ask you how you want to debug (this needs proper configuration which should be ok by default).

See also [Difference between Debugger.Launch and Debugger.Break](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3759308/difference-between-debugger-launch-and-debugger-break)